# page redirection not working in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, cordova, ngcordova

We are new to `angular js`. We are developing ng-Cordova apps.
We are facing problems with page redirection. We have two  `HomeSecond`,`DetailsPage` pages.In HomeSecond  have loadFeeds method using this method we get data form server when page load.

```
$scope.loadFeeds = function () {
            alert("Start");
            $http({
                  method : "GET",
                  url : 'http://192.168.3.118:2244/api/PostPets/GetData'
                  }).then(function mySucces(response) {
                         var DogsPostLists = response.data;
                      $scope.DogsPostLists = DogsPostLists;
                           }, function myError(response) {
                          alert(response);
                          //console.log('ERR'+response.message);
                          });
            }
            $scope.loadFeeds();
```

We have button for redirection to `DetailsPage` code like this

```
$scope.toggleImage = function (index) {
    $location.path("/page11");
    }
```

After that we move to page11(DetailsPage). Now We have back button in DetailsPage. We tried like this

```
$scope.HomePageMove = function (){
      $location.path("/page4/page9");//HomeSecond page
        }
```

When we click on back button.it's move to HomeSecond page but loadFeeds not calling.

```
routes.js

.state('home', {
               url: '/page4',
               templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
               controller: 'homeCtrl'
               })
     .state('home.homeSecond', {
               url: '/page9',
               views: {
               'side-menu21': {
               templateUrl: 'templates/homeSecond.html',
               controller: 'HomeSecondCtrl'
               }
               }
               })
    .state('selectDogDetailsPage', {
               url: '/page11',
               templateUrl: 'templates/selectDogDetailsPage.html',
               controller: 'selectDogDetailsPageCtrl'
               })
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are calling, "/page4/page9".

Shouldn't it be,

```
$scope.HomePageMove = function (){
      $location.path("/page9");//HomeSecond page
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply page4 is root page so we need redireced with home(page4) page4 have Menu page guide to us

Comment: what does 'side-menu21' do then?